# Magento 2: theme translation does not work

Tags: magento2, i18n, locale-translation

Magento 2.2.9

I have a third party module (`vendor/mirasvit/module-search-autocomplete`). It comes with several translatable strings (`i18n/en_US.csv`).

I want to translate the string `Show all %1 results →` in my theme folder (`theme/i18n/de_DE.csv`): `"Show all %1 results →","Zeige alle %1 Ergebnisse →"`

That file already contains a lot of working translations (mainly from magento core) but no matter what I do, this string will not be translated. I cleaned caches (magento and browser), I deleted everything in pub/static/frontend, setup di compile... nothing helps.

Just for testing purposes I also modified the translatable string in the modules core. Just to make sure it is the right one. Nothing.

It only works when I put a de_DE.csv file into the modules i18n folder. But that is not what I really want to do for obvious reasons.

How? What? Why? It does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Does that string exists in the module mirasvit/module-search-autocomplete csv file? I had a similar case that I wanted to translate a placeholder, but it was generated with js in the module. Hence it was not possible to translate it at that time.
One other case could be that you should specify which module that part of translation is for.
something like
Qty,Qty,module,Magento_Catalog

Comment: Yes, as my workaround works fine. That de_DE.csv file is a direct copy of the original en_US.csv.